# bind event fail on Chrome but OK in Firefox when browser back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I bind a scroll event when scroll to the page end,do some function.
On this page , have links to other page.
Once to another page,and click back button on browser.
This Event still do well in FireFox,**but does not work in Chrome**

```
        $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
                               a()
                    }
                }
        })
```

Comment: How can it work in any browser? Fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in chrome ie 10 and fire fox and it worked and it worked.
every time i scroll to the end of the document  it throws the alert. But make sure you have an element on a page that is largere then a screen itself. E.G. if your screen is 900px height, you need an element in your page that is 1000px, so that the re was a scroll bar. and exactly 50 px before the end of the document you will receive the alert.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
      if (($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 50)) {
           alert("scrol top is more then document height");
          }
      });
});
```